# Is possible to render a partial in index.html in public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is possible to render a partial in index.html in public folder?

I need to render the partial 'app/view/showcase/_last_five' into '/public/index.html'.

I tested with:

```
    <%= render(:partial => "showcase/last_five" )%>
```

but no process the code.

I need to move the index to a controller?
What I can load with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to move the contents of index.html to a controller (like PagesController#index). Files present in public/ folder are generally served directly by the web server.

Comment: Thanks was looking everywhere for something that assured me that should be in controller.

Answer (score 0):

To make your application's URL match the behavior of the public/index.html page, you can make the default route match the index action of your showcase controller. Then you can render the partial there, as Adam suggested.

In yourAppName/config/routes.rb, you can match the relative URL "/" to e.g. "showcase#index" like so:

```
YourAppName::Application.routes.draw do
    match "/", :to => "showcase#index"
```

or

```
    root :to => "showcase#index"
```

So if a user types in your application's URL, like "http://yourappname.com/", the request will be processed by the showcase controller, and the index action will be called.

Also, not sure if you already knew this, but in order to use ruby code in your view files, it has to be a .html.erb file. Straight up .html files will not be parsed for Ruby code.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected but did not know for sure. And I just saved another turn for the book "Agile Web ...".